# C#: Exponential Format Specifier

Tags: c#, formatting, number-formatting, exponential, mantissa

I have a double number:

```
element.MaxAllowableConcLimitPpm = 0.077724795640326971;
```

I need to display it as

> 7.7725e-2

when I try to use it:

```
element.MaxAllowableConcLimitPpm.ToString("e4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

it returns

> 7.7725e-002

How to say that mantissa should have one symbol instead of 3 ?

Format like this:

```
.ToString("0.0000e0")
```

returns

> 5.0000e2

instead of

> 5.0000e+2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use a custom numeric format string - standard numeric format strings always have at least three digits in the exponent.

Example with a custom string:

```
using System;

public class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        double value = 0.077724795640326971;
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.0000e+0")); // 7.7725e-2
    }
}
```

From the documentation for [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#EFormatString) (emphasis mine):

> The case of the format specifier indicates whether to prefix the exponent with an "E" or an "e". **The exponent always consists of a plus or minus sign and a minimum of three digits.** The exponent is padded with zeros to meet this minimum, if required.

Comment: it lost '+' if mantissa positive or zero. 5.0000e3 instead of 5.0000e+3